# Cannot delete old Exchange account from Internet Accounts in El Capitan

Tags: exchange, macos, microsoft

I have an old Exchange account, I don't have access to it nor remember the password.

I want to delete it.

When I go to Internet Accounts, select it, and click "-" to delete it, it asks "are you sure", I say "yes", and nothing happens. The account is still there.

Answer (score 1):

If it was installed using a Profile sometimes you cant remove it using Internet Accounts. Instead you need to go to System Preferences -> Profiles and remove the email profile.